# convert the format into new format javascript

Tags: javascript

```
26(5p) => 19005(3p)
6827(3p) => 6939(3p)
```

the arrow gets converted to `'-'`

Replace this format to

```
#slices= '5p.26-3p.19005,3p.6827-3p.6939'
```

using JavaScript

I tried the below code, too long to execute

```
for(let i=0; i<this.selectedSliceMulti.length; i++)
{
    let replacevalue = this.slicesList[0].replace(/\=>/,'');
    let replacevalue2 = replacevalue.replace(/ /g,'');
    let replacevalue3 = replacevalue2.split(/[(\)]/);
    replacevalue3.splice(4);
    let halfWayThough = Math.floor(replacevalue3.length / 2)
    let arrayFirstHalf = replacevalue3.slice(0, halfWayThough);
    let arraySecondHalf = replacevalue3.slice(halfWayThough, replacevalue3.length);
    console.log(replacevalue3)
    //this.slicesList[0].replace('\=>\','-')
}
```

Comment: It'd be nicer if you can explain what you're trying to do. What you're expecting this code to do.

Comment: You're looping for the length of `this.selectedSliceMulti`, but operating on `this.slicesList[0]` every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a single regexp replacement using capture groups:

```js
var arr = ["26(5p) => 19005(3p)", "6827(3p) => 6939(3p)"];

var newArr = arr.map(str => str.replace(/(\d+)\((\w+)\) => (\d+)\((\w+)\)/, '$2.$1-$4.$3'));
var result = newArr.join(",");
console.log(result);
```